# Trouble printing text file in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Hey guys so I've been trying to get c++ to print a text file in visual studio pro 2013. This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    char word[30];

    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen("Text.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", word);

        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Text.txt was a text file I made in visual studio and is stored under source files. Currently all that happens is the window prints the pause message... any suggestions for how to fix it? Sorry for the noob question :p

Comment: Check return value of `fscanf()`

Comment: Try put `printf("%s ", word);` before `fscanf(fp, "%s", word);` in while-loop. or Use  `fgets` and `fputs`. E.g `while(fgets(word, sizeof word, fp)) fputs(word, stdout);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that worked! thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: As a new member of Stack Overflow, you would do well to take the introductory [tour]. One of the many things SO is *not*, is a *forum*. It is a Question and Answer site instead. It is not habitual to edit a question or its title to indicate it is "solved". See the other questions and answers. If you feel @BLUEPIXY's proposed answer helped, request a formal answer so you can accept it, or, alternatively, post it as an answer under your own name.

Comment: While that may compile with a C++ compiler, the actual implementation libraries and headers appear to be just C. If you were doing this in C++ using C++ libraries it would probably look something [more like **this**](http://pastebin.com/u02zmh0w).

Comment: Any reason you don't use C++ facilities for this? Coding C-style in C++ is at best bad style.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using any other function that would print anything to the screen.

`scanf()` is a function that reads and to a certain extent interprets standard input (typically user input).

Equivalent printing function is `printf()`.

Both `scanf()` and `printf()` functions are controlled via formatting string, which tells them either how to interpret data to be output, or how to interpret standard input that is supposed to be stored in variables.

Formatting string is provided as a c string, that is a null terminated string, that is an array of characters with the last one being a `NUL` (`\0` entity; `'\0'` character). In that string you can provide information on type and order of data to be read or written. Fe. `%s` signifies a string. Proper string can contain bytes of all values except for `NUL`, which is considered a terminating character. But with regard to input, a whitespace is considered the end of a string, so `scanf()` will cease reading upon encountering a whitespace.

When you're reading data you have to provide the function with address, and it will store value there. In case of string, the way strings work in C, you pass value from pointer to character. Pointer to character stores a value that is an address in memory. This address may be of a single character, but it can also be an address of first character in an array, where consecutive characters are stored in following memory cells. However information on how much memory, starting from the address that is stored in that pointer, is allocated for the purpose of storing this character array, is not kept automatically. In fact, it may be indeed a single character which is thus capable of storing at most 0 significant characters + the null terminating character, if you intend to use it as a string.

In your case, `word[]` is an array and `word` evaluates to position of `word[0]` in memory. Entire array contains 30 characters, so you can store at most 29 significant characters + null. However `scanf()` provides no guarantee that it will stop at 29th character, the way you use it. Perhaps You should consult some reference page for `scanf()` and learn more about formatting string, I vaguely remember that maybe you could somehow limit your read with proper formatting string. Maybe something like `%29s`.

So once again what happens is your provide `word` to `scanf()`, so you provide an address of first character in `word[]` array, and `scanf()` stores input there and in the following cells, possibly overflowing your buffer. (Read about buffer overflow too, while we're at it, it's important problem)

When you're printing information, you don't need adresses to store to, but values to translate to human readable form. However it so happens that in case of strings you still provide the address of first character, so it will look almost the same.

Comment: Note that `""` is a "proper string", i.e., the empty string, and it is eqivalent to `(char){ '\0' }`.